# Zend_Form using subforms getValues() problem

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-sub-form

I am building a form in Zend Framework 1.9 using subforms as well as Zend_JQuery being enabled on those forms. The form itself is fine and all the error checking etc is working as normal. But the issue I am having is that when I'm trying to retrieve the values in my controller, I'm receiving just the form entry for the last subform e.g.

My master form class (abbreviated for speed):

```
Master_Form extends Zend_Form
{

  public function init()
  {

    ZendX_JQuery::enableForm($this);

    $this->setAction('actioninhere')
         ...
         ->setAttrib('id', 'mainForm')

    $sub_one = new Form_One();
    $sub_one->setDecorators(... in here I add the jQuery as per the docs);
    $this->addSubForm($sub_one, 'form-one');

    $sub_two = new Form_Two();
    $sub_two->setDecorators(... in here I add the jQuery as per the docs);
    $this->addSubForm($sub_two, 'form-two');
  }

}
```

So that all works as it should in the display and when I submit without filling in the required values, the correct errors are returned. However, in my controller I have this:

```
class My_Controller extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
  public function createAction()
  {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = new Master_Form();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
      if ($form->isValid($request->getPost()) {

        // This is where I am having the problems
        print_r($form->getValues());

      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I submit this and it gets past isValid(), the $form->getValues() is only returning the elements from the second subform, not the entire form.

Comment: why are you not using init() instead of createForm? This way you don't need to call anything. Shorter way of testing postback: if ($this->_request->isPost()). There is a > missing at $form->isValid. Try $form->isValid($_POST).

Comment: Hi tharkun, sorry yes I am actually using init() in my actual form. This is dummy code, not my actual code as the form itself is huuuuuuge. I will update the code above though for clarity.

I believe that I have interpreted the way that Zend_Form deals with the posted forms incorrectly, so will post my new solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem. It seems to me that getValues is using array_merge, instead of array_merge_recursive, which does render to correct results. I submitted a bug report, but have not gotten any feedback on it yet.
I submitted a bug report (http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8078). Perhaps you want to vote on it?

Comment: Blockhead, this appears to have been resolved in the last week or so as my bug request's status has been updated, but not had a chance to test it yet. See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8022?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

I think that perhaps I must have been misunderstanding the way that the subforms work in Zend, and the code below helps me achieve what I wanted. None of my elements share names across subforms, but I guess this is why Zend_Form works this way.

In my controller I now have:

```
if($request->isPost()) {
  if ($form->isValid($request->getPost()) {
    $all_form_details = array();
    foreach ($form->getSubForms() as $subform) {
      $all_form_details = array_merge($all_form_details, $subform->getValues());
    }
    // Now I have one nice and tidy array to pass to my model. I know this
    // could also be seen as model logic for a skinnier controller, but
    // this is just to demonstrate it working.
    print_r($all_form_details);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem to get value from subforms I solve it with this but not my desire one
code:
in controller i get value with this code that 'rolesSubform' is my subform name
$this->_request->getParam ( 'rolesSubform' );

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. Used post instead of getValues.

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

There are times when getValues does not return the same values returned by $post.
Must be a getValues() bug.